# AWS ubuntu EC2 instance reachability check failed

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, flask, amazon-ec2

Hi I deployed a flask web app in the AWS ec2 ubuntu instance. At the beginning, it is normal and I can access to site by the site domain. But after a week, I can not access to site. And I check EC2 instance instance status checks, there is check failed information as shown in the below picture.
[image]

So once has the above issue, I have to stop and restart my instance, my site is becoming normal. I don't know how to solve it, and I don't want to restart the instance frequently.

Comment: Has this only happened once? Or multiple times?

Comment: Hi @MarkB It happened frequently, maybe once in a week

Comment: It sounds like your application has a memory leak or something. You need to setup monitoring to detect that issue. If you want AWS to automatically recover from issues like this on your behalf, then you need to setup your application to be deployed via an auto-scaling group.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for your comment, how to do it via auto-scaling group

Answer (score 0):

So why does it gets solved after restarting? This is because all the performance specification like CPU, memory, and disk (along with IOPS) gets reset and the instance can pass the reachability check.

It is possible that performance issues, including low IOPS or high memory usage, could indirectly impact the reachability of an instance if they lead to overall system instability or unresponsiveness.

For example, suppose an instance is heavily overloaded with high CPU or memory utilization, it may become unresponsive or slow to respond to network requests, which could trigger a reachability check failure.

So to address this issue, you could utilize the AWS offering of [AWS Compute Optimizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/compute-optimizer/latest/ug/what-is-compute-optimizer.html) which can guide you to the right sizing of an instance by providing the recommendation and can also show the current [finding classification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/compute-optimizer/latest/APIReference/API_InstanceRecommendation.html) of an instance.

Comment: ...or check your logs.

Comment: @symcbean how to check the logs?